# Adding missing dates to JSON that had no sales

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, c#-4.0

I have a piece of code that returns a JSON result like following:

```
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allData.OrderBy(x => x.DataDate.Value.Date)
                                           .Select(item =>
                                                   new { Date = item.DataDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 
                                                         Sales = (int)item.SalesForDay,  
                                                         Revenue = (int?)item.RevenueForDay.Value }));
```

As you can see from above, the line of code returns all dates that HAD sales...

For example graph would have:

```
10th of October - 3 Sales - Revenue 1100$

8th of October - 3 Sales - Revenue 1100$

4th of October - 3 Sales - Revenue 1100$

2nd of October - 3 Sales - Revenue 1100$

1st of October - 3 Sales - Revenue 1100$
```

The returned statement should return all dates from Current date (12th of October) back into past 30 days that had NO SALES, and place also 0.00 revenue for those dates...

How could I achieve this?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: That's either a LINQ or database question. Not related to ASP.NET, JSON or `DateTime`. What is `allData` and where does it come from? If `allData` doesn't contain anything for those dates you'll have to generate those records somehow

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you are wanting. I assume you would need a `.Where(x => x.DataDate <= DateTime.Today && x.DataDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10) && SalesForDay == 0)`

Comment: I'd strongly suggest cleaning up the code too.  Separate the query from serialization because it's *very* hard to read it or understand what it does.

Comment: And what will be the date-range?

Comment: @StephenMuecke My most fav. developer!! :D Basically what I want is just add missing dates that had no sales from current date back into past from this list, and the list is coming from the database

Comment: @AnkushJain -30 days from current dates into past => add dates that have no sales and no revenue , and simply to place those values both to 0 0 with specific date

Comment: @User987 why don't you write a query that returns records with no sales then?

Comment: Do you mean the dates that do not exist in the db?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yesss that's it

Comment: @StephenMuecke frmo current date, back to past -30 days

Comment: Probably easiest to get the distinct dates that do exist between the dates, and then get the dates that do not exist in that result

Comment: @StephenMuecke How exactly ? Xd

Comment: Are there any duplicate dates in the table? And why is `DataDate` a nullable field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181752/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user987).

Comment: @StephenMuecke no there aren't duplicates.. It's nullable because there are records with different "type" (tinyint) column in the table... And for different types I don't set the datadate... But there isn't worry for nulls since I filter them out in the query

Answer (score 1):

Here is a customized solution for your problem. Though I know this is not the best solution but will solve your purpose.

First, create a DTO

```
public class SalesDataDTO
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Sales { get; set; }
    public int Revenue { get; set; }
}
```

Second, copy this utility function

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
{
    for (var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
        yield return day;
}
```

Finally call this function to get your desired output:

```
public List<SalesDataDTO> GetReportData()
{
    // 1. Define date range
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30);

    // 2. create object to store final result
    List<SalesDataDTO> saleDataList = new List<SalesDataDTO>();

    // 3. create basic data
    foreach (DateTime day in EachDay(fromDate, toDate))
    {
        saleDataList.Add(new SalesDataDTO { Date = day });
    }

    // 4. get actual data from db
    List<SalesDataDTO> actualReportData = allData.OrderBy(x => x.DataDate.Value.Date)
                                .Select(item =>
                                    new SalesDataDTO
                                    {
                                     Date = item.DataDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                     Sales = (int)item.SalesForDay,
                                     Revenue = (int?)item.RevenueForDay.Value
                                    }); 

    // 5. a bit customization
    saleDataList.ForEach(record =>
    {
        var actualData = actualReportData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Date.Date == record.Date.Date);
        if (actualData != null)
        {
            record.Sales = actualData.Sales;
            record.Revenue = actualData.Revenue;
        }
    });

    // 6. return data
    return saleDataList;
}
```

Later you can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saleDataList);` to further serialize your data.